# Send mongodb aggregation criteria through url query string

Tags: c#, mongodb

what I'm trying to achieve is build a MongoDB aggregation stage on the client side then send it through an URL query string to the web API to get the results based on those criteria.

I'm debbugging with postman with this url:

```
http://.../monsters/aggregate?pipes={"$match":{"name":"foo"}, "$max": 2}
```

In the controller I have:

```
    [HttpGet("aggregate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByAggregate([FromQuery(Name = "pipes")]string pipes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pipes))
        {
            BsonDocument d = BsonDocument.Parse(pipes);

            var p = PipelineDefinition<T, T>.Create(d);

            IAsyncCursor<T> result = await _monsterService.AggregateAsync(p);

            return Ok(result.ToListAsync());
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

This is not working, the error message :

> MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field..

But with this url I get what I want:

```
http://.../monsters/aggregate?pipes={"$match":{"name":"foo"}}
```

How to parse mongodb pipeline to a correct json format for the url query string then deserialized to a mongodb pipeline stages on the api side ?

Is there a better way to do it, is this logic possible?

I tried some urls form [thirdparty](https://restdb.io/docs/querying-with-the-api) but can't make it work...

Any help will much be appreciated!

Comment: Could you describe why it's not working ?

Comment: I just updated with more information. thx

Comment: What's the goal of `$max`: 2 in your pipeline ?

Comment: To get a limit of 2 objects.

Comment: Could you quickly try: `[{"$match":{"name":"foo"}}, {"$limit": 2}]` ?

Comment: this is the erro: FormatException: Cannot deserialize a &#x27;BsonDocument&#x27; from BsonType &#x27;Array&#x27;

Comment: When debugging, on the pipelinedeffinition ("p") I get one item in the array, so the whole string as one object in the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation pipeline is an array of stages so you need to pass an array if you want to have flexible endpoint. Every JSON that represents single pipeline can have only one field on a root level and that property is supposed to represent pipeline stage name, like `$match`. That's why your example with `$max` is not working.

What's more if you want to limit to `2` objects you should use [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) instead of [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/index.html) (which is used to aggregate data). So your aggregation pipeline should look like this:

```
[{"$match":{"name":"foo"}},{"$limit":2}]
```

Since you have to pass to an API an array instead of single string it's way easier to use `POST` instead of `GET` endpoint and pass that array in request's body

```
public class Payload
{
    public string[] Pipes { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("aggregate")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByAggregate([FromBody]Payload payload)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pipes))
    {
        var p = PipelineDefinition<T, T>.Create(payload.Pipes.Select(BsonDocument.Parse));

        IAsyncCursor<T> result = await _monsterService.AggregateAsync(p);

        return Ok(result.ToListAsync());
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

And then you can send `POST` request with following body:

```
{
    "pipes": [ "{\"$match\":{\"name\":\"foo\"}}","{\"$limit\":2}"  ]
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how they do it [restdb.io](https://restdb.io/docs/querying-with-the-api). I think they trim the string to get pipeline stages... ?

Comment: What if I don't wanna use Linq?

Comment: Yes, you can pass all the pipelines as one string and then split that string by some separator - thats possible. Linq is not required here, what I want to show is that you need multiple BsonDocuments in your pipeline to filter and then limit results. Yes, you can check if the array is not empty and if BsonDocument.Parse works for all the elements